# Wait in for loops for async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, wait

I need run startFunc function synchronously and "wait" in for loop to finish task, to run it again. I can't use await in startFunc().
I need something like .wait() in c#
I except result:
start 1
end 1
start 2
end 2 etc...

```
function callToDB(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function startFunc (i) {
  console.log('start', i);
  await callToDB(1000);
  console.log('end', i);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  startFunc(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `for` loop in an `async` function as well, so you can `await` each call to `startFunc`:

```js
function callToDB(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function startFunc (i) {
  console.log('start', i);
  await callToDB(1000);
  console.log('end', i);
}

(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    await startFunc(i);
  }
})();
```

Another method would be to continually chain `.then`s:

```js
function callToDB(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function startFunc (i) {
  console.log('start', i);
  await callToDB(1000);
  console.log('end', i);
}

let prom = Promise.resolve();
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  prom = prom.then(() => startFunc(i));
}
```

Or you could use `.reduce` and continually pass along the last Promise as the accumulator, rather than assign to an outside variable:

```js
function callToDB(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function startFunc (i) {
  console.log('start', i);
  await callToDB(1000);
  console.log('end', i);
}

const finalProm = Array.from({ length: 5 })
  .reduce(
    (lastProm, _, i) => lastProm.then(() => startFunc(i)),
    Promise.resolve()
  );
```

Comment: That is a nifty snippet